# What is this vba syntax?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sorting

I've been given a spreadsheet to work on by a colleague, upon looking at it I found this in a macro

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding_Work_DB").ListObjects( _
    "BS_Outsanding_Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "BS_Outsanding_Work[[#All],[Date]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

Is this real syntax?  I've never seen anything like that in vba.

More specifically, it's this part which is confusing me:

```
Add Key:=Range( _
    "BS_Outsanding_Work[[#All],[Date]]")
```

The spreadsheet already does almost everything they want it to, but this piece of code doesn't run, it throws the "Method range of object _global failed" error.

In short: are the square brackets real syntax, and if so what are they trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure about the brackets but maybe you could debug step by step and see where the code stops running...

Comment: and apparently it's not entirely wrong, see here: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables (search for -> Set rng = Range("Table1[#All]").Resize)

Comment: It looks like it's attempting to sort a table called "BS_Outstanding_Work", does that object exist in your workbook?

Comment: @ChrisMack yes it does.

Comment: This is one big long method chain. To work out which piece is broken, run each method individually, assigning to a variable.

Comment: Is the table in the workbook actually called "BS_Outsanding_Work" or is it perhaps "BS_Outstanding_Work"? If so, then you've misspelled it in the code and that's probably what's causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. It is actually a part of the code which sorts the table on `date` column in ascending order.

See this example.

1. Let's say you have worksheet called `Outstanding_Work_DB`
2. Let's say you have a table called `BS_Outsanding_Work`
3. Let's say your table looks like this

Table

[image]

If you would like to sort that table on date on ascending order then you would use this code

```
Sub Sample()
    '~~> PART 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding_Work_DB").ListObjects("BS_Outsanding_Work").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear

    '~~> PART 2
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding_Work_DB").ListObjects("BS_Outsanding_Work").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("BS_Outsanding_Work[[#All],[Date]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    '~~> PART 3
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding_Work_DB").ListObjects("BS_Outsanding_Work").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

**Explanation**

`SortFields.Clear` clears all `SortFields` object. The SortFields collection is a collection of SortField objects. It allows developers to store a sort state on workbooks, lists, and autofilters.

`ListObjects("Outstanding_Work_DB")` is your Excel table.

`SortFields.Add` creates a new sort field and returns a SortFields object.

`Range("BS_Outsanding_Work[[#All],[Date]]")` is saying that sort all the table on date field (including header). Try this two lines of code in the Immediate window :)

```
?Range("BS_Outsanding_Work[[#All],[Date]]").Address

?Range("BS_Outsanding_Work[Date]").Address
```

`Order:=xlAscending` is self explanatory. The sorting has to be in ascending order.

The last part of the code applies the code

In short

- **FIRST PART**: Clears all `SortFields` object
- **SECOND PART**: Creates a new sort field
- **THIRD PART**: Applies the sort

After the code is run

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is adding a sort description to the table. To execute the sort, you would then use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outstanding_Work_DB").ListObjects("BS_Outsanding_Work").Sort.Apply
```

As it's failing on the `Range` part, I'd imagine that the 'Date' column either no longer exists or has been renamed.